# /npm/bin/npm-cli.js: not found on Azure app service - node app

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I am trying to deploy the nodejs app to Azure but I am getting the below error.

- 2021-07-08T10:22:38.234570707Z
  /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/npm: 1:
  /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/npm: ../npm/bin/npm-cli.js: not
  found
- 2021-07-08T10:22:38.244796509Z npm info lifecycle express-typescript-starter@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script

This is the output I am seeing application logs on Azure.

App Service is the free plan with Node 14 as a runtime environment running on Linux. I have verified all the files, everything looking good.

Even I checked node modules as well. The folder is there but the error-specific file i.e inside node_module `npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. It is not there.

But it's not on my local as well and there it's working fine.
I am deploying through Github action.